# Don't multiply a field if another field equals 5 or 10

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running this query which is populating my temp table which I then export from. The priceSingle is calculated by simply doubling the fare.  However, for some rows, the category is a single fare anyway, so I don't want to double it. The query is actually embedded in a string in PHP, but the SQL looks like:

```
INSERT INTO temp
    SELECT cruises.code AS sailingId, live, 'USD', 'optioncode', 'rateOptionName', '2',
           category AS cabinCategory, fare*2 AS priceSingle, fare AS priceDouble,
           supplements_usa.adult AS priceAdditional
      FROM fares_usa, supplements_usa, cruises
     WHERE fares_usa.cruise_id = supplements_usa.cruise_id
       AND cruises.id = fares_usa.cruise_id AND cruises.live = 'Y'
```

How can I avoid doing `fare*2` when `category` equals 5 or 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN category = 5 OR category = 10 THEN fare ELSE fare * 2 END
```

Comment: great does that just drop in place of fear*2 AS priceSingle

Comment: Yes; the `CASE ... END` is an expression replacing your `fare * 2` expression.

Comment: yep that's done it, will tick when it let's me , thanks @Jonathan Leffler